# Application stops after several hours with Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'

Tags: android

My app should work 24/7

But when the application runs around 20-50 hours, the application closes without any messages.

this is what i see in Logcat:

```
2021-04-30 23:33:36.779 19235-19235/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 19235 (itspecial.idesk), pid 19235 (itspecial.idesk)
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Amlogic/franklin/franklin:9/PPR1.180610.011/20200831:userdebug/test-keys'
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19235, tid: 19235, name: itspecial.idesk  >>> com.itspecial.idesk <<<
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  00004b23  r2  00000006  r3  a3667918
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     r4  00004b23  r5  00004b23  r6  bba1d5fc  r7  0000010c
2021-04-30 23:33:37.023 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     r8  bba1d6e0  r9  00000001  r10 00000000  r11 00000000
2021-04-30 23:33:37.024 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     ip  00000041  sp  bba1d5e8  lr  a35f60e5  pc  a35ede72
2021-04-30 23:33:39.016 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-04-30 23:33:39.016 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001ce72  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+62)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.016 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00016bc4  /system/lib/libminikin.so (abort_with_message(char const*)+24)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.016 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00016c20  /system/lib/libminikin.so (__ubsan_handle_add_overflow_minimal_abort+24)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000f2ef  /system/lib/libminikin.so (void minikin::LayoutCache::getOrCreate<minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor>(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, bool, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor&)+542)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000edf1  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutWord(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutPieces const*, minikin::Layout*, float*, minikin::MinikinExtent*, minikin::MinikinRect*, minikin::LayoutPieces*)+204)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000e999  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutRunCached(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutPieces const*, minikin::Layout*, float*, minikin::MinikinExtent*, minikin::MinikinRect*, minikin::LayoutPieces*)+244)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000e86b  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayout(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::Bidi, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit)+210)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00088ef1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::MinikinUtils::doLayout(android::Paint const*, minikin::Bidi, android::Typeface const*, unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, minikin::MeasuredText*)+148)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 003718ad  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::Canvas::drawText(unsigned short const*, int, int, int, float, float, minikin::Bidi, android::Paint const&, android::Typeface const*, minikin::MeasuredText*)+76)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000c9035  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::drawTextString(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jstring*, int, int, float, float, int, long long)+86)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 003d0ddb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.view.RecordingCanvas.nDrawText [DEDUPED]+194)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0002cb29  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawText+120)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00031073  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.text.BoringLayout.draw+106)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.017 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00026b13  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.widget.TextView.onDraw+2962)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00025031  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+2000)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0001e873  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+690)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.018 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 00020357  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList+70)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 000204e9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList+144)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 0001e6a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 0002edef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList+86)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 000273a9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList+80)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 0002dc87  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw+110)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0002e5ed  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw+1636)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 0002f0a5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw+340)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 0003500b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals+10674)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 00039487  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal+150)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 00037499  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run+48)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 0002474b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run+186)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 00020bf1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+496)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00022737  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame+934)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 00031b85  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+68)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 0003c375  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+52)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 0000e523  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+58)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 0005cf25  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loop+892)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 00417dbb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+42)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 0024ea41  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::MaybeDoOnStackReplacement(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, int, art::JValue*)+1464)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 003f08e7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpMaybeDoOnStackReplacement+86)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 004174f4  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+66164)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 00aee6d4  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+928)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.019 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 001cc757  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+146)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 001e34fb  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+754)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 003eceeb  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 0040ab94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 00385172  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 001cc6a3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 003df753  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+890)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 0041c2ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 003f13eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 00350a6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 00351eb5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+960)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 00302bd9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 001121ff  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (offset 0x10c000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.020 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 003f12e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+226)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 000a1031  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+136)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 001e8835  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+232)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 001e3511  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+776)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 003ebf0f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+442)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 0040aa14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 00c0f296  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 001cc6a3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 003df753  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+890)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 0041c2ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #86 pc 00a130e9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2896)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #87 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #88 pc 003f13eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #89 pc 000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.021 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #90 pc 00350a6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #91 pc 00350889  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+304)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #92 pc 002949cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+476)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #93 pc 0006cb73  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #94 pc 0006ed9b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+462)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #95 pc 0000198d  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+724)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #96 pc 00088f55  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #97 pc 00001677  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+46)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #98 pc 00019a27  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeIjP6soinfoEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIjS4_NS_4hashIjEELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIjS4_NS_8equal_toIjEELb1EEENS_9allocatorIS4_EEE14__erase_uniqueIjEEjRKT_+90)
2021-04-30 23:33:39.022 30744-30744/? A/DEBUG:     #99 pc 007fec3e  [stack:bb222000]
```

Tested on a several devices with Android 6 and Android 9 and on the emulator. Problem occurs only on Android 9 (and maybe higher) on emulator and on real device.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: @HenryTwist added the full text of the error, that's all I have at the moment, this is the first time the device was connected to the studio to output the logs.

Comment: `Why does something running so long crash`. Seems like a classic memory issue. `'ubsan: add-overflow` seems like there is something that is getting added a number and resulting in an overflow. Anything of such sorts ?